# Present alert without animating back swipe buttons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swipe

I have a tableView where I want to have an edit and a delete button when the user swipes a cell to the left. For this I use the tableView's `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` delegate method. This is working fine, it presents the two buttons as expected. 
I want to present a confirmation alert when the user taps on delete. This is also working fine, but when the alert is presented, the cell animates back to its original position. So the delete, edit buttons are not visible anymore. This is what I'd not like to have.

Is there a way to prevent the cell from animating back when presenting an alert?

Comment: Please show your code. Also, check for table reload.

Comment: ^ I think not. Not a duplicate. OP wants to disable default behavior of the cell, such as when you scroll up or down, the available options should be there.

Comment: Could you please show your codes in ```trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt``` and how you do the presentation of the alert?

Comment: Add a breakpoint in cellForRow method and check what method call is causing the reload.

Comment: I did put a breakpoint in `cellForRow` but it doesn't get called after tapping the delete button. @Mosbah

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for this problem. 
In order to set the actions for the buttons, you need to initialize `UIContextualAction` class. This class has a handler which has a bool value of type `(Bool) -> Void`. So basically when you set the handler closure you can return true or false, which means that the action completed. So if you call the completion when the user tapped the alert's button then the buttons will stay visible until the alert is dismissed.

The code what I tried and it's working is the following:

```
// 1
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    //2
    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") { _, _, success in
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: { _ in
            //3
            success(true)
        })
        alertController.addAction(alertAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
}
```

1. Implement the `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` delegate method to set the swipe actions. You can also do the same thing if you need buttons when swiping to the right by implementing the `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` delegate method.
2. Setup an action for your button. In the handler closure of the `UIContextualAction` you can setup the alertController.
3. Call `success(true)` when the 'OK' button of the alert is tapped.